# Changing values in an R data frame in randomly selected rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assuming the df below:

`df <- data.frame(id = c(1:20),  x1 = rep(c(0, .35, 0, 0),5), x2 = rep(c(0.8,0.8,0,0),5))`

Note that x1 has 25% of the rows valued at 0.35 and x2 has 50% of the rows valued at 0.8

Now suppose that I want to increase the number of rows in x1 with the value of 0.35 to 75% by randomly adding that beta to cells that are valued as 0.

Additionally, suppose that I want to decrease the number of rows in x2 with the value of 0.8 by randomly removing that beta from rows that are valued as 0.85.

How can I programmatically do that? I’ve played with it a number of ways, but they’re all extraordinarily brute force, and I imagine there is a more elegant and efficient approach that I’m overlooking. It’s easy enough to brute force it with this small matrix, but, as you may imagine, the real matrix is orders of magnitude more complex.

Truly appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding right, you want to change some values at random. Maybe an approach like this will work, shown for your `x1`.

You can mirror this logic for your `x2`, and play around with the probability depending on how many values you want to randomly change on average.

```r
library(dplyr)

# value of x1
x1_beta <- 0.35

# probability cutoff
xl_p_cutoff <- 0.5

# generate a random uniform value for each row
# if x1 is zero and the random value is above the cutoff, set as the beta value
df %>% 
  mutate(p_x1 = runif(n()),
         new_x1 = if_else(x1 == 0 & p_x1 > xl_p_cutoff, x1_beta, x1))
```

The above can also be combinded into a single line.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = if_else(x1 == 0 & runif(n()) > xl_p_cutoff, x1_beta, x1))
```